# Combining vector displacement and standard black and white displacement nodes

Tags: node-editor, displacement, vector

I am currently working on an ocean scene. The water uses a subdivided plane with waves that are displaced via the vector displacement node in the material.

I would like to add another whirlpool effect displacement on top of this, using a black and white image I have created in photoshop.

[image: Node setup]

[image: Black and white displacement .jpg]

What is the best way to mix these two displacements together, with the whirlpool jpeg displacement added onto the existing vector displacement?

Thanks in advance!
[image: Ocean Render]

Comment: It depends on how you want to combine them. Are you asking how to rotate the wave vectors toward the center of the whirlpool based on the whirlpool's slope?

Comment: @HISEROD I really just want to add the whirlpool displacement on top of the existing vector displacement. I tried mixing them both before going into the vector displacement, but this didn't really work, which I guess is due to the black and white displacement map not being vector format? I'm unsure if you can convert it into that same vector format, or maybe mix the two different displacement nodes somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this setup with a *Vector Math* set to *Add*.  It should work for you.

[image: Vec]

[image: Illustration]

Comment: I just had this idea for illustration, check out the compression on that color picker!

Comment: I used this shape because I was curious how it would handle the object origin.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!